# How to show the matrix is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a $A \in R^{m \times n}$ of rank $n$ and $I$ is $m \times m$ matrix. How to show that the below matrix is invertible?

\begin{pmatrix}
   I & A \\
   A^* & 0 \\
  \end{pmatrix}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that since rank of $A$ is $n$, we have $n\leq m$ and $A^*A$ is invertible. Therefore, if we write the LDU decomposition of the block matrix into an upper triangular, diagonal, and lower triangular matrices (see e.g. the proof of matrix inversion lemma [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity#Derivation_from_LDU_decomposition)), we obtain the inverse to be
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
I & A\\ 
 A^*& 0
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
=\begin{bmatrix}
I & A\\ 
0 & I
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 I& 0\\ 
0 & (A^*A)^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
I & 0\\ 
-A^* & I
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

There exists $B\in\Bbb R^{n\times m}$ such that $BA$ is the $n\times n$ identity. Play with it.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Recall that a matrix is invertible if and only if it is full rank.

What is the rank of $\begin{bmatrix}
   I & A \\
   A^* & 0 \\
  \end{bmatrix} \in\Bbb R^{(m+n)\times (m+n)}$?

Answer (score 1):

You can do block Gaussian elimination; for simplicity, set $C=A^*A$ which is invertible, because it has full rank: if a vector satisfies $Cx=0$, then $x^*Cx=0$, which implies $Ax=0$ and therefore $x=0$ by the assumption on $A$.

\begin{align}
\left[\begin{array}{cc|cc}
I & A & I & 0\\
A^* & 0 & 0 & I
\end{array}\right]
&\to
\left[\begin{array}{cc|cc}
I & A & I & 0\\
0 & -A^*A & -A^* & I
\end{array}\right]
&& R_2\gets R_2-A^*R_1
\\[6px]&\to
\left[\begin{array}{cc|cc}
I & A & I & 0\\
0 & I & C^{-1}A^* & -C^{-1}
\end{array}\right]
&& R_2\gets -C^{-1}R_2
\\[6px]&\to
\left[\begin{array}{cc|cc}
I & 0 & I-AC^{-1}A^* & AC^{-1}\\
0 & I & C^{-1}A^* & -C^{-1}
\end{array}\right]
&& R_1\gets R_1-AR_2
\end{align}
Thus
$$
\begin{bmatrix} I & A \\ A^* & 0 \end{bmatrix}^{-1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
I-AC^{-1}A^* & AC^{-1}\\
C^{-1}A^* & -C^{-1}
\end{bmatrix}
$$